How to do mechanically created dependencies with Bazel?
With GNU Make, it's possible to use a generated file as a part of Makefile logic, for example for mechanically created dependencies of targets:
.deps:
    echo "a: b c" > $@ # in real code would scan `a` to determine its dependencies

include .deps

How to do a similar thing with Bazel?
